# Can Redis be used exclusively as a persistence strategy when a large amount of data is involved?

Tags: architecture, nosql, redis

From what I understand, Redis runs entirely in memory and just synchronizes its data back to disk, which is the main reason why it's so fast.

Their site says that [virtual memory](http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory) is deprecated, and the prose surrounding that statement seems to indicate that their near-term plans don't include continued support for databases that are larger than system memory (which, quite honestly, describes most of the databases I've worked with, even RDBMSes which have the benefit of normalization).

Does this mean that Redis is no longer a suitable (long-term) candidate for the primary or only data store in a reasonably data-dense or high-traffic application? Should I be sticking to SQL/Mongo/Raven/etc. for the main event and only consider Redis for the occasional bells and whistles (caching etc.)?

Or are there people who've successfully scaled with Redis, without using the deprecated VM feature? And if so, how?

P.S. I've read about [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) which would apparently be a solution, but it looks like it's nowhere near ready for prime time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until redis cluster is ready, your best bet is going to be pre-sharding. Make a large number of instances and use a consistent hash to divide your keys among them. Then, when your dataset grows (or you need more performance), take half of the instances and move them over to a different physical machine.

But it's not a fit for every scenario, that's for sure. If you have lots and lots of data, use a different database.

You could also use redis for a sub-set of your data - the time critical parts - and a different database for the rest.